# datapick jquery как вставить в поле свою дату

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

как вставить в input свою дату? placeholder , value - не помогают

код

```
<form action="" method="GET" class="w-100">        

        <div class="input-group mb-3 mt-3">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" aria-describedby="button-addon2" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" value="2020.01.01">
           <div class="mr-3 ml-3 pt-2">-</div>

           <input type="date" class="form-control" aria-describedby="button-addon2" id="datepTo" name="dateTo" value="{$dateTo}">


            <input type="hidden"  name="maska_poisk" value ="{$maska_poisk}">

        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary ml-3">Поиск</button>
        </div>


</form>
```

Comment: `<input type="date" value=<?=date("Y-m-d")?>`

Comment: да,вы правы,не вставлялась дата,тк была в неправильном формате :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, что именно у Вас не получается, поскольку Вы не привели свой код в вопросе полностью. Мне кажется, Вы не используете параметр `format: "yyyy.mm.dd"` при инициализации datepicker'а. Инициализация производится через параметр `value="..."` тэга. Вот Вам пример из рабочего кода с использованием `datepicker()`:

разметка html + PHP. Переменные `$from` и `$to` - типа [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php).

```php
<div class="input-group input-daterange">
    <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
    <input id="from" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $from->format('d.m.Y'); ?>">
    <div class="input-group-addon">по</div>
    <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
    <input id="to" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $to->format('d.m.Y'); ?>">
</div>
```

Инициализация (javascript)

```js
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
    language: "ru",
    format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
    todayHighlight: true,
    templates: {
        leftArrow: '<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i>',
        rightArrow: '<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>'
    }
});
```

Comment: да, проблема была в неправильном формате, я пытался в датапикер запихнуть через value даты не в том формате,который принимает датапике.